# Solve the following integral equation and find closed form

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, functional-equations

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  a continuous function. Solve the integral equation:

$u(t) = f(t) + a\int_{0}^{t}u(s) \, ds $

finding a closed form for the solution.

I was trying to solve this exercise but I am having some trouble: the exercise does not say wheter $u$ should be continuous or not. If I assume continuity, the substitution $h(t) = \int_{0}^{t}u(s)\,ds $ turns the equation in a linear ODE and I am done . If $u$ is not continuous there the trouble begins:
Since I can not use fundamental theorem of calculus, I followed two paths : I tred to mollify $u$ by convolution and taking the sequence of solutions $\{u_{\epsilon}\}_{\epsilon > 0}$ to the equation

$u_{\epsilon}(t) = f(t) + a\int_{0}^{t}u_{\epsilon}(s) \, ds $

and setting $u= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } u_{\epsilon }$ I tried to prove this function solves the original but failed.

I tried also ,since $u$ is integrable, to consider the fourier series of the left and the right side but I can not switch integral and series in the right side. I am out of ideas I would like a full solution more than some hints.

Comment: Take the derivative on both sides and solve the differential equation using [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First-order_equation).

Comment: Two problems: f may be not derivable and I am assuming $u$ not continuous I can not apply derivative. If  it is not clear from the edit I can rewrite anyway

Comment: Derivatives always exist in a suitable [distributional sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions), you can worry about that after getting the solution formula.

Comment: You right I did not get in what sense you said to apply derivative. Is it too much if I ask you to write a solution,please. It would be very appreciate

Comment: It is better if you do it yourself, the Wikipedia link pretty much walks you through the process.

Comment: Ok, once I found the closed formula with the variation of parameters method, how to I generalize it ,considering the case $u$ is derivable only in distributional sense?

Comment: The formula will not contain any derivatives of $u$, only a derivative of $f$, which is integrated.

Comment: I think I  got it all thank you so much

Comment: You can prove that $ u $ is continuous. For the problem to be well-posed (in the sense that $ u $ must be a function, and the integral sign denotes the usual notions of integration, like Lebesgue integration), you must have that $ u $ is locally integrable, and then [the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) implies that $ t \mapsto \int _ 0 ^ t u ( s ) \ \mathrm d s $ is continuous. As $ u $ is the sum of that function with the continuous $ f $, it is continuous, too.